# IllegalStateException raised when installing feature from zipped update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

I'm experimenting with installing an Eclipse feature from the zipped update site from command line. To do this I use following command:

```
eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:///d:\Eclipse_Workspaces\update-site-dummy_workspace\com.experiment.updatesite\experiment_update_site_1.0.0.zip!/ -installIU com.experiment.feature.one.feature.group -profile PlatformProfile
```

It works, however just before the end of installation process it rises an exception like this one:

```
Installing com.experiment.feature.one.feature.group 1.0.0.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet.
        at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.getWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:92)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.provisional.p2.ui.ProvisioningOperationRunner.requestRestart(ProvisioningOperationRunner.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.ProvUIActivator$1.notify(ProvUIActivator.java:117)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningEventBus.dispatchEvent(ProvisioningEventBus.java:108)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:227)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.core.ProvisioningEventBus.publishEvent(ProvisioningEventBus.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.SimpleProfileRegistry.broadcastChangeEvent(SimpleProfileRegistry.java:350)
        ....
Operation completed in 1277 ms.
```

The requested feature is installed, but I feel bad about this exception - especially it won't look good on a someone's computer ;)

[Here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t99010.rhtml) I found some information about this exception:
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet

This usually comes when someone tries to run a Java application against an OSGi bundle with java -classpath .... . It really means that the workbench plug-in hasn't started yet, and so calls to getWorkbench() fail. This is essentially a race condition, and can be solved by either expressing an explicit dependency on that bundle or bumping up that bundle to a higher start level than the workbench. Generally not seen, but if it is, that's what's happening. "

My question is: **Does anyone have an idea how to work around rising this exception?** (E.g. by adding some vm options to the install command)

PS I'm using Eclipse 3.4 and there is no way to upgrade it to something newer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I've been struggling a bit with this problem and finally I found a solution. There was missing `-destination` argument in the install command, so the correct one is:

```
eclipsec.exe -nosplash -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director -repository jar:file:///d:\Eclipse_Workspaces\update-site-dummy_workspace\com.experiment.updatesite\experiment_update_site_1.0.0.zip!/ -installIU com.experiment.feature.one.feature.group -profile PlatformProfile -destination .
```

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the bundle **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui** is active in your environment. By default you don't launch Workbench, so that bundle should be in **Resolved** state in OSGi runtime. I'm not sure why this bundle is started in your environment, you can check file ***configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator/bundle.info***, mark the bundle as not auto start.

Comment: Unfortunately is's already set to `false`. I didn't pay attention to the fact it's an UI plug-in. So I thought that removing `-nosplash` option might have been helpful, but it wasn't. Anyway +1 for the effort.

Comment: A trick way is removing the **org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui** from your eclipse. I suggest you using latest eclipse(such as 3.7), the director application should support the repository generated by 3.4.